# How to buffer writes to an External Drive using an Internal SSD

Tags: ssd, cache, opensuse, lvm, btrfs

This question is a bit of an odd one, I'll try to be as detailed as I can be.

I'm repurposing an old computer to serve as an in home backup solution. The final resting place for the data is an external G-Drive connected via USB 2.0 (I told you it's an old computer.) I would like to figure out how to use some space on the computer's new shiny SSD drive to buffer writes to the external drive. I am using OpenSUSE Leap 15, with a server installation.

So far I have found [bcache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcache), which I could set to write-back mode and get something similar to what I'm looking for. The problem is the partition I would be buffering uses btrfs (transparent compression) and there have been [issues reported using the two together](https://www.hdevalence.ca/blog/2013-09-21-notes-on-my-archlinux-install). The [arch wiki says that this was fixed in 3.9](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/bcache) but I don't find that anywhere in the linked source.

There's also [lvmcache](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/lvmcache.7.html). The only reference to writeback that I see is a brief blip in the man page, without much further explanation. I'm also already using lvm to divvy up the SSD into various partitions with thin pools, so I would be worried that using lvmcache would require me to either create a new dedicated lvm-vg across the two drives, to prevent the thin pools from spreading to the external. Additionally there are notes in the BTRFS wiki that using BTRFS on top of anything block-level could cause problems.

[DM-Cache](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dm-cache) is another highly configurable option that I am still in the process of learning. As it works on the block level, it is still possible that it may conflict with btrfs.

The final option is setting up a SLOG based ZIL with zfs. [This source](https://www.ixsystems.com/blog/o-slog-not-slog-best-configure-zfs-intent-log/) says that with a 1Gbps connection the largest a SLOG would have to be is .625 GB, because it would flush every 5 seconds. However, based on extensive testing, the highest sustained write speed I can get to this drive is 30MB/s. This would imply that it would take 20 seconds to dump a .625GB slog to the ZFS drive. <s>(Update: Based on [This source](https://pthree.org/2012/12/06/zfs-administration-part-iii-the-zfs-intent-log/) and [this source](https://www.45drives.com/wiki/index.php?title=FreeNAS_-_What_is_ZIL_%26_L2ARC) the SLOG device is not intended to boost throughput, just to reduce latency.)</s> (Update to the Update: In the comments Dan clarified what is meant by this. It is still likely that the ZIL could be utilized in this scenario.)

I *know* that large writes will inevitably be bottlenecked by the external connection. I figure that anything on the order of tens of GB will end up at 30MB/s. My goal is not to solve that problem. I'll likely use rsync to send data to the external, so I would like to speed up *most* transfers of less than 10GB.

I'm basically curious as to if anyone else has done something similar to this, and has recommendations, or can point to a specific option as being better than others. Right now I'm considering the ZFS/SLOG option to be the best one, using a 10GB slog drive, but I have no idea how that large of a drive will play with the 5 second flush.

tl;dr: What's the best way (though I know not all of this is exactly *recommended*) to buffer about 10GB worth of data on an internal drive that will then be transferred to an external drive?

Comment: You have the weirdest problems, the fanciest solutions and well researched ideas. I love it!

Comment: I've not come across this problem before, but have you looked at dm-cache? (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dm-cache)

Comment: @davidgo LVMCache [is based on](http://strugglers.net/~andy/blog/2017/07/19/bcache-and-lvmcache/) dm-cache, which would potentially open up the same issues caused by block level solutions + btrfs. That being said, there seems to be a **lot** of configurability within dm-cache, including throttling the data transference between cache and origin. This means that if I can solve the transparent compression problem, dm-cache might be a better block layer device than the other two. Thanks for the input! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe any of the solutions you mentioned would work fine (minus the interactions between `bcache` / LVM and BtrFS -- I don't know more than you do there). The choice probably comes down to what's the easiest for you to understand, set up, and maintain.

Personally, I would choose ZFS because:

1. I have a lot of experience with it.
2. It provides an all-in-one solution for this use case (compression plus using SSDs to cache reads and/or writes).
3. It provides a bunch of other fancy features (snapshots and clones, dedup, RAID-Z, replication with `zfs send`, encryption, compressed RAM cache, ...) that you may find useful in the future even if you don't use them now. There's also a healthy open source community that's constantly adding new features.

Comment: Do you think expanding the SLOG size would help to prevent bottlenecks? The only concern that I have with ZFS is that the ZIL will flush every 5 seconds. I'm unsure if that means that writes are _halted_ during flush, or what happens. I'll have to read more into it. ZFS was what I was leaning toward as well.

Comment: I did some more research and it seems like a ZIL SLOG might not be the way to go. [This Article](https://pthree.org/2012/12/06/zfs-administration-part-iii-the-zfs-intent-log/) suggests that the SLOG will improve latency, but not throughput. As the device will be accessed via the network, latency isn't a huge concern. [This one](https://www.45drives.com/wiki/index.php?title=FreeNAS_-_What_is_ZIL_%26_L2ARC) seems to agree. 

whomp whomp :(

Comment: @Zyra: Right -- using a slog (or any write cache) will speed up writes until you've filled it up, at then everything will slow down to the speed of the main pool while things are pushed out of the cache. This **does** improve throughput when your required throughput spikes above what the main pool can offer, but if your workload consistently needs higher throughput than your main pool, the only way to use a faster main pool.    Regarding your other question, writes are not blocked on the buffer flushing, they are only blocked on earlier writes to the ZIL / slog.

Comment: Oh! Well then. ZFS might just be the winner in this situation. I will edit the edit that I just made, and if I don't get any additional responses, I'll pick your answer. Thanks so much for the clarification.

Comment: Maybe this is being approached from the wrong end. As I understand you're both discussing how to speed up and stabilize the cache by way of picking which fs works best for the intended purpose, while you still have the glaring limitation of the USB 2.0 connection. The mentioned 30MB/s. It might be worth to add a 2nd USB drive and have both extDrives set as RAID 0.. or a Stripe. Wikipedia claims this increases performance. I don't think it's too much of a leap to think that having two drives onto which the  cache can offload will increase performance.

Comment: @RicardoS. Definitely — adding additional drives and putting them into a striped zpool, or using an internal hard drive instead of a USB-connected drive, would help performance of the main pool. Write bandwidth scales approximately linearly with the number of drives in ZFS (either for striping or for more complex configurations like RAID-Z that have more redundancy to protect against disk failures), and probably for most other striping solutions as well.

Comment: @Dan Striping is done via vdevs right? From my understanding all drives to be placed into a vdev at the time of creation [though this is being worked on](https://twitter.com/OpenZFS/status/921042446275944448?s=09) (There's an excellent talk in the comments, but I'm sure you've seen it). I don't currently have plans to add anything else to this setup (it seems more prudent to skip expanding on a broken idea and just grab a second hand xeon server from ebay or something), but in the future it would be neat to know if I can stripe across vdevs versus only _within_ vdevs. Does that make sense? lol

Comment: @Zyra Right, striping is configured via the configuration you give to `zpool create`. You can also add more disks to a pool via `zpool add` today ([example](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E54801/gayrd.html)) but you won't be able to add disks to a RAID-Z until after the project you mentioned is released.